# How to disable HUD in Unity 2D?

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-2d, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

I am using Ubuntustudio 12.04 with Unity 2D. It delivers the HUD.

Since I work with audio and graphic applications, exploring features (filters, effects) is important. So I would like to disable HUD.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? Just don't hit *Alt* :p Or is some app ignoring the standards again and using *Alt* in its keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @Timmie - If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: You use menus as always before, whether you use HUD or not. The HUD doesn't change anything unless you choose to use it. I don't really understand that reasoning. But if you want to, it should be possible. I couldn't find any keys in dconf-editor. Might be a bug. You can file one on Launchpad.net by pressing Alt+F2 and typing "ubuntu-bug unity-2d"

Comment: @RobinJ emacs relies heavily on [Alt]